# How to switch modules in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I want to use `SW[15]` to switch between module `A_7seg` and `B_7seg` but it does not work. (2 modules work separately)

```
module mix(input CLOCK,input [15:0]SW,output reg [15:0] led,output [3:0] an,output reg[7:0] seg);
    generate
    case(SW[15])
        1'b0:A_7seg (.CLOCK(CLOCK),.an(an),.seg(seg));
        1'b1:B_7seg (.CLOCK(CLOCK),.SW(SW),.led(led),.an(an),.seg(seg));
    endcase
    endgenerate
endmodule
```

Comment: `generate` block is used to instantiate modules conditionally at 'compile-time', not 'run-time'. Either you use a parameter to select which module to instantiate, which leads to either `A_7seg` or `B_7seg` is present; or you instantiate both (more area consumption), and use a wire to select which one is currently working.

Comment: May i know how to add the wire in this case? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since '2 modules work separately', the simple way is to use `SW[15]` to select between 2 modules' outputs.

```
module mix(
    input CLOCK,
    input [15:0] SW,
    output reg [15:0] led,
    output reg [3:0] an,
    output reg [7:0] seg
);
    wire [15:0] B_led;
    wire [3:0] A_an, B_an;
    wire [7:0] A_seg, B_seg;

    // if not using 'generate' block, modules are instantiated at
    // the top level, not in other 'if'/'case'/... structures.
    // and name the 2 instantiations
    A_7seg u_A_7seg (.CLOCK(CLOCK), .an(A_an), .seg(A_seg));
    B_7seg u_B_7seg (.CLOCK(CLOCK), .SW(SW), .led(B_led), .an(B_an), .seg(B_seg));

    // this extra circuit is needed to select between the two
    always@(*)begin
        if(SW[15])begin
            led = B_led;
            an  = B_an;
            seg = B_seg;
        end
        else begin
            led = 16'h0;  // <-- I assume the inactive value for 'led' is all-zero
            an  = A_an;
            seg = A_seg;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

You may also want to use `SW[15]` to gate the inputs to the one that is not currently working to reduce power consumption.

You need to figure out the schematic before you understand how to write the code.